# The man I want to go there. <- Is this grammatical?

Tags: word-usage

One of my friend who's leaning English as I am, kept insisting me that that above sentence is grammatical and has same meaning with "I want the man to go there".

I googled it, but none did I find for any reference. Do natives really take that natural sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, the sentence does not appear to be completely grammatical. It looks more like a sentence fragment because it gives the feeling that the subject, *the man*, is missing the verb, *is*: *The man I want to go **is** there*. So, you can tell your friend that he is wrong.

However, the sentence would mean exactly the same thing as *I want the man to go there* if you add *he is* or *here's* to the beginning of it:

> **He is** the man I want to go there.
>
> **Here's** the man I want to go there.

Answer (score 2):

The man I want to go there.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence if you drop "the".

Man, I want to go there.

You use "man" in informal English to address a male person.